# QueryFullProcessImageName not work,return 0

Tags: vba, vb6

QueryFullProcessImageName always return 0,can not retrieve process path,code below,need you help,thanks.

`Public Declare Function QueryFullProcessImageName Lib "Kernel32.dll" Alias "QueryFullProcessImageNameA" (hProcess As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal lpExeName As String, lpdwSize As Long) As Long

Private Function GetProcessImageName(ByVal lProcessID As Long) As String
Dim hProcess As Long
Dim sBuf As String
Dim sChar As Long

hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION Or PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 0, lProcessID)
If hProcess Then
sBuf = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
QueryFullProcessImageName hProcess, 0, sBuf, MAX_PATH
sBuf = Left$(sBuf, sChar)
 End If
GetProcessImageName = sBuf
CloseHandle hProcess
End Function`

Comment: code can not retrieve path info in my win7(64 bit) 32 bit excel,I have no way to continue,i hope it will be works in my excel vba,thank your help.

Comment: hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION Or PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, lProcessID) ,also not work

Comment: GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess, sBuf, MAX_PATH),not work also,return 0,please your help

Answer (score 0):

if you use the [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) Function you'll be able to get more information of why it returns 0.

Comment: Ret = GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess, sBuf, MAX_PATH)
  LastError = GetLastError()
LastError return 0. Can you help me?

Comment: Hi， Err.LastDllError is 6 ，do you know how to correct this code ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, in VB6, you must use Err.LastDllError, not the GetLastError function. Error 6 means "The handle is invalid"--see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues in the code.

First, sChar is never initialized.

Also, the first parameter to [QueryFullProcessImageName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx) is an "In" param so it should be passed ByVal.  That may be the cause of the invalid handle error 6.

This thread has some helpful information about how to get the length back when calling QueryFullProcessImageName:  http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?805537-RESOLVED-Excel-Crash-when-call-API-function-QueryFullProcessImageName-in-excel-VBA-of-win7.

Finally, per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880(v=vs.85).aspx, "A handle that has the PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION access right is automatically granted PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION", so remove the unneeded access right.

With that info, try something like this (untested):

```
Public Declare Function QueryFullProcessImageName Lib "Kernel32.dll" Alias "QueryFullProcessImageNameA" _
    (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal lpExeName As String, ByRef lpdwSize As Long) As Long

Private Function GetProcessImageName(ByVal lProcessID As Long) As String
    Dim hProcess As Long
    Dim sBuf As String
    Dim sChar As Long

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 0, lProcessID)
    If hProcess Then
        sBuf = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
        sChar = MAX_PATH
        QueryFullProcessImageName hProcess, 0, sBuf, sChar
        sBuf = Left$(sBuf, sChar)
    End If
    GetProcessImageName = sBuf
    CloseHandle hProcess
End Function
```